# How to output HTML element names in Yard documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation, yard

I'd like to include some HTML element names, like `<label>`, in my ruby class documentation generated by Yard. But it is not working. For example, the sentence

```
# Returns a <label> field...
```

Becomes, after processing by Yard

```
Return a field...
```

The `<label>` element is actually passing verbatim through Yard making it to the browser as raw HTML.

I tried using `&lt;label&gt;` instead, and that got escaped so I ended up with `&lt;label&gt;` in the resulting documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: When I try `<label>` with backticks, I end up with empty backticks, ``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yard uses normal [RDoc markup](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md) by default:

> By default, YARD is compatible with the same RDoc syntax most Ruby developers are already familiar with.

And [RDoc has this to say](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/files/README.html):

> Putting a backslash before inline markup stops it being interpreted, which is how I created the table above:
>
> ```
> _italic_::     \_word_ or \<em>text</em>
> *bold*::       \*word* or \<b>text</b>
> +typewriter+:: \+word+ or \<tt>text</tt>
> ```

That suggests that this:

```
# Returns a \<label> field...
```

should work but that did nothing useful for me, just more of the same "pass it through to the HTML" nonsense. However, wrapping the `<label>` in RDoc's typewriter markup did produce something useful so try this:

```
# Returns a +<label>+ field...
```

Comment: http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md ==> takes forever to load

Comment: @ribamar rubydoc.info generates and caches HTML needed, it only takes a long time on first access.

Comment: `\<pre> my text </pre>` doesn't work for me neither with rdoc nor with yard